# possible to see the shiny App log in App itseltf (browser)

Tags: shinydashboard, shinyapps

I built one simple shiny app and user facing error because of issue in input data, as an admin I can see the error in log if I login to server but user also wants to see the issue so that they can fix ( the format issues).
Wanted to know if it is possible to get log ( at least errors) in app ( browser itself)

Answer (score 1):

You can try my package {[spsComps](https://github.com/lz100/spsComps)}. Use the exception handling function `shinyCatch`. This function will log on the message, warning or errors both on server side and user side.

Here is the reference:  https://systempipe.org/sps/funcs/spscomps/reference/shinyCatch.html

And you can try the demo under server components tab: https://lezhang.shinyapps.io/spsComps/

The basic usage is very simple:

```r
library(spsComps)

ui <- fluidPage(
  spsDepend("toastr"),
  sliderInput(
    "a", label = "change number", -10, 10, 5
  ),
  verbatimTextOutput("b")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$b <- renderText({
    shinyCatch({
      if (input$a < 0) stop("need > 0")
    }, blocking_level = "error")
    input$a
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

For example, you have a slider from -10 to 10 and you need the value > 0. If users have < 0, there will be an error. `shinyCatch` will log the error both on server and UI as a toast message. `blocking_level = "error"` is saying block the rest of the code in the same reactive context, so in this case you don't see the print output from `input$a`. You can choose to continue without adding this. Then there will be an error message but the code continues to execute.

additional examples: https://systempipe.org/sps/dev/spscomps/server/#shinycatch